# Problem : iPhone graphics go mad !

Tags: iphone, graphics, layout, multithreading, quartz-2d

I faced a really stranged problem recently. I am doing a timetable organizer, and I draw each event in a DayViewController with Quarz 2D, then I add a "glass effect" picture (PNG).

But randomly, as I switch between days, the layout go really bad.
Here is a link to see the good appearance and below the bad one :
http://toucotton.ifrance.com/image.jpg

---

I don't know why this is happening. Some times I have the color of past events that are partially laid on the half of displayed ones. Is there any cache Core Graphics has that has to be flushed or something ??
Actually, I create a DayViewController in a background thread but I add its view to my superview in the main thread ...

I just wanted to know if you've ever seen such bizarre things like that before ?!
Bye and thanks in advance.

Comment: Drawing/layout errors are common with custom views. Nobody can help you without seeing how you're handling this in your app (ie, show us some code).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to erase your drawing area before drawing?